# Adapt screen color to time of day slowly (like f.lux, but better)

Tags: windows, display, health, ergonomics

[f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) is a tool that changes the screen color to match the time of day.  It's big weakness is that it only has two options for the duration to adjust the color of the display: 20 seconds or 60 minutes.

Are there any [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) apps that perform a similar function as f.lux, but allow more flexibility in the duration to change the color of the display?  Specifically, I would like something that can change the color more slowly than 60 minutes, just like the real sun.

***UPDATE:***

So far, no answers have been posted, so I have removed the gratis (free of cost) requirement.  I would still prefer gratis software, but I am opening this question up to recommendations of commercial software as well.

Comment: And ideally ideally you would want to link it to sun up/sun under times?

Comment: @JanDoggen Good question Jan.  Ideally yes, but I'm fine to manually enter it.  I do also like how f.lux tells the user the time to sunset/sunrise, but that's gravy and not essential.